# Page load time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, pageload

How to get the page load time of an application which has n number of CSS, js, images, etc? How to do the configuration in JMeter?I have tried integrating selenium, but I can only find the scenario load time not the exact load time of a page.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special setting responsible for parsing the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and retrieval of so called ["embedded resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/): images, CSS, JavaScript, sounds, fonts, etc.

It lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

If you have more than one HTTP Request sampler - consider adding [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element, if you define the setting there - it will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers in the HTTP Request Defaults [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dmitri T's solution, but I think that solution is to simulate new users every time. You need to treat Jmeter as a protocol tool rather than a smart fully featured browser. I suggest you do scripts recording and put parallel controller in place and put recorded scripts under the parallel controller.
You need to make sure you understand each time a page is loading, which ones are cache, which ones are not. Using recording scripts to add them under parallel controller, I think you can download the parallel controller in Jmeter plugin manager..